# D-Bus list name

Tags: c, dbus, gio

How can I list all names in the D-Bus sessionBus with C?

I'm looking for the [C GIO](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus-lowlevel.html) equivalent for the [dbus.list_names python method](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/api/dbus.bus-pysrc.html#BusConnection.list_names)

I want to list all names in «org.mpris.MediaPlayer2» which as example could be «org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.clementine, org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.someotherplayer, ...»

There is an application called «qdbusviewer» which does something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific GIO method for this tasks,

Bus names can be listet with a call to the «[org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#bus-messages-list-names)», filtering has to be done later.

Obtaining informations about the bus can be done with the [introspection](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio-D-Bus-Introspection-Data.html) methods.

Answer (score 2):

Information about the interface names, methods and arguments should be in the [introspection section](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio-D-Bus-Introspection-Data.html).

You can request information about an interface (e.g. `org.mpris.MediaPlayer2`) using the [g_dbus_node_info_lookup_interface ()](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio-D-Bus-Introspection-Data.html#g-dbus-node-info-lookup-interface) method, to which you can give a `GDBusNodeInfo` argument, which should contain the path of the dbus object you want to query.

From this call you can get back a [GDBusInterfaceInfo](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.26/gio-D-Bus-Introspection-Data.html#GDBusInterfaceInfo) object which contains information about the methods and arguments of the requested interface.

Comment: I was not searching for the method, signal and property names, I was searching for bus names.
I found the «org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames» method which does what I searched